# Radius of Convergence for $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n-2\right)!}\left(2n+1\right)x^{2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

Let $f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n-2\right)!}\left(2n+1\right)x^{2n}$

I want to find the radius of convergence.

So I wrote the series with $t=-x^2$, like: $-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2n+1}{\left(2n-2\right)!}t^{n}$

And while using the ratio test, I find the limit to be $0$.

So that means that the series with $t$ converges for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, which means that for $x$ it converges for every $-x^2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is that also mean that it converges for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$? What is $\forall -x^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your argument shows that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n+1}{(2n-2)!}t^n$ converges for every $t\in\Bbb R$. And, given $x\in\Bbb R$, since $-x^2\in\Bbb R$, then the original series converges too.

If you have doubts about this approach, you can think as follows: the original series clearly converges if $x=0$ and, if $x\ne0$,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!}(2n+3)x^{2n+2}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-2)!}(2n+1)x^{2n}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+3}{2n+1}\frac1{2n(2n-1)}|x|^2=0,$$and therefore your series converges (and it converges absolutely).

Comment: Thank you so much!
Follow up: to find an explicit formula, would you recommend to think about the series of $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$ ?

Comment: I recommend that you think about *both* of them.

Comment: Great, thank you!